# Is max(a, b) Analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Wikipedia briefly references the concept of an analytic function in several variables, but I don't have any reference to this idea in any of my analysis texts at hand:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Analytic_functions_of_several_variables

So, I have no idea how to start on this question. Given a, b real, is max(a, b) analytic? And if so, can it be continued on the complex plane?

Comment: No: $f(a,b)=\max(a,b)$

Comment: a, b are meant as the several variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not even differentiable. What happens if you fix $b$ and let $a$ vary from one side of $b$ to the other?

It is piecewise linear though. If one cuts the plane along the diagonal $x=y$ then in the left/upper component the function is just $y$, while in the right/lower component the function is $x$.

Comment: Good point, thank you.